# how to use the api data res with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi i know this question its a little dumb but im learning to use react native with hooks and some things give me troubles to understand.
I have this api call with axios

```
    const getRFC = ({vLastName,vSecondLastName,vName,vSecondName,vBirthDate}) => {
axios. post(`http://exitusdesarrollo.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com/AppForceControllers/controllers/GetRfcController.php`, {  vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vBirthDate })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.resultRFC);
    })
}
```

and yeah in console log prints what i need, so what i dont know how to do it is how to use the res.data.resultRFC outside the function.
normally it would be something like

```
`const RFC= res.data.resultRFC;
        this.setState({ RFC});`
```

but since im using hooks this throws me error, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `useState` inside your function:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

    // inside your component
    const [rfc, setRfc] = useState(null);


   // inside your axios callback
   setRfc(res.data.resultRFC);

   // later in your component / render you can use rfc
   {rfc && <Text>{rfc}</Text>}
```

for more reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: yes this works, thanks a lot. I have to wait like 5 minutes to mark as correct, i will do it on time, tnx for your help pal